# The instruction expected additional account keys in execute sale function in auctioneer of Metaplex Auction House

Tags: solana, metaplex

I'm getting this error while executing sale in auctioneer. I'm using Auctioneer js sdk.

```
'Program neer8g6yJq2mQM6KbnViEDAD4gr3gRZyMMf4F2p3MEh invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Instruction: ExecuteSale',
    'Program hausS13jsjafwWwGqZTUQRmWyvyxn9EQpqMwV1PBBmk invoke [2]',
    'Program log: Instruction: AuctioneerExecuteSale',
    'Program log: ProgramError occurred. Error Code: NotEnoughAccountKeys. Error Number: 47244640256. Error Message: The instruction expected additional account keys.',
    'Program hausS13jsjafwWwGqZTUQRmWyvyxn9EQpqMwV1PBBmk consumed 68367 of 137171 compute units',
    'Program hausS13jsjafwWwGqZTUQRmWyvyxn9EQpqMwV1PBBmk failed: insufficient account keys for instruction',
    'Program neer8g6yJq2mQM6KbnViEDAD4gr3gRZyMMf4F2p3MEh consumed 131196 of 200000 compute units',
    'Program neer8g6yJq2mQM6KbnViEDAD4gr3gRZyMMf4F2p3MEh failed: insufficient account keys for instruction'
```

I saw some people complain about this.Is the issue fixed?
does this PR fixes the bug?
https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/pull/588

i tried to copy the changes and redeploy the program. I have a new Auctioneer address. so how can i use that with the old sdk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That PR will fix the issue and should be merged in shortly! I'd recommend waiting for that so you don't have to modify the SDK manually.